# Simplifying $(\sin^6x + \cos^6x) - (\sin^4x + \cos^4x) + \sin^2x\cos^2x$

Tags: trigonometry, weierstrass-factorization

$(\sin^6x + \cos^6x) - (\sin^4x + \cos^4x) + \sin^2x\cos^2x =$

Right Answer: $0$, but I could not solve this question. Help me please.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$

Comment: $$(\sin^6x + \cos^6x) - (\sin^4x + \cos^4x) + \sin^2x\cos^2x = \sin^4x (\sin^2x - 1) + \cos^4x (\cos^2x - 1) + \sin^2x \cos^2x. $$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(\sin^6x + \cos^6x) - (\sin^4x + \cos^4x) + \sin^2x\cos^2x $$
$$= \sin^6x + \cos^6x - \sin^4x -\cos^4x+\sin^2x\cos^2x$$
$$= \cos^6x(\tan^6x + 1 - \tan^4x\sec^2{x} -\sec^2x+\tan^2x\sec^2x)$$
$$= \cos^6x(\tan^6x + 1 - \tan^4x(1+\tan^2x) -(1+\tan^2x)+\tan^2x(1+\tan^2x))$$
$$= \cos^6x(\tan^6x + 1 - \tan^4x-\tan^6x -1-\tan^2x+\tan^2x+\tan^4x)$$
$$= \cos^6x(0)$$
$$= 0$$

Answer (score 1):

With $c:=\cos^2 x,\,s:=\sin^2 x$, it suffices to note $$c^3+s^3-c^2-s^2+cs=(c+s-1)(c^2-cs+s^2).$$

Comment: Could you explain how you would come up with that expression assuming you had never seen it before? Is there an algebra trick I'm missing out?

Comment: @ElieLouis It's natural to divide $c+s-1$ into the original expression to see whether the remainder is $0$. In this case, the factorisation of $c^3+s^3$ as $(c+s)(c^2-cs+s^2)$ proves helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$; if you square that, you get
$$
\sin^4 x + 2\sin^2 x \cos^2 x + \cos^4 x = 1,
$$
which you can turn into 
$$
\sin^4 x + \cos^4 x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x \cos^2 x 
$$
and that lets you get rid of the 4th powers in the left hand side.

Can you run with that idea?